# flutter RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..9: 10

Tags: flutter

```
List<Book> bookList = [];

  BookService();

  final TextEditingController appBarTextController = TextEditingController();

  Future<List<Book>> callGoogleDio() async {
    Response getGoogleDio = await Dio().get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${appBarTextController.text}");

if (getGoogleDio.statusCode == 200) {
  var map = getGoogleDio.data;
  int totalItems = map["totalItems"];
  print(totalItems);

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var indexOfMap = map["items"][i];
    if (indexOfMap != null) {
      String imageUrl =
          map["items"][i]["volumeInfo"]["imageLinks"]["thumbnail"] ?? "";
      String title = map["items"][i]["volumeInfo"]["title"] ?? "empty title";
      String subTitle =
          map["items"][i]["volumeInfo"]["subtitle"] ?? "empty subtitle";
      String previewLink = map["items"][i]["volumeInfo"]["previewLink"] ?? "";
      print(map["items"][i]);

      bookList.add(Book(
          imageUrl: imageUrl,
          title: title,
          subTitle: subTitle,
          previewLink: previewLink));
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
} else {
  print("error");
}
return bookList;
}
```

E/flutter ( 2732): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..9: 10
E/flutter ( 2732): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
E/flutter ( 2732): #1      BookService.callGoogleDio (package:book_store/main.dart:41:38)
E/flutter ( 2732): 
E/flutter ( 2732):

***How can I solve this problem? Occurred during the process of adding to the list.***
Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..9: 10

Comment: Can you try something like this for (int i = 0; i < map["items"].length;  i++)

Comment: Oh, Thank you. Range error resolved. However, the error of adding only 10 lists remains the same.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I wrote the wrong explanation of the question. I want to add all the books(TotalItems is the maximum quantity) I searched to the book list.

Comment: totalItem is type of int.

Comment: Oh, I found a solution. Thank you for your attention to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `.length` method to iterate properly through the result.

```dart
for(var i = 0; i < map["items"].length; i++){...}
```

Or to get rid of code duplication, use a `.forEach()`

```dart
map["items"].forEach((item) {...})
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. But I wrote the wrong question. Sorry. I want to receive the number of data up to totalItems(int) and apply it to the bookList, is there any way?

Comment: I changed 20 to totalItems, but there was a rangeError.

Comment: Oh, I found a solution. Thank you for your attention to my problem.